# iOS – Subclassing to avoid code duplication and protocols

Tags: objective-c, protocols, subclass

I need all my view controllers to be able to show the Message compose view controller (`MFMessageComposeViewController`) and also handle `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` method to see whether a message was sent/cancelled/failed. So my idea was to subclass `UIViewController` impement these methods in this view controller. And then have all my view controllers that need to be able to send messages subclass the above view controller.

So like `BaseMessageViewController : UIViewController`

And then `ViewController1 : BaseMessageViewController`, `ViewController2 : BaseMessageViewController` and so on...

So when I was at it, I thought I would create a protocol like this:

```
@protocol MessageProcessing

@required

- (void)presentMessageCompose;
- (void)processMessageCancelled;
- (void)processMessageSent;
- (void)processMessageFailed;

@end
```

But I'm not sure if `BaseMessageViewController` should conform to this protocol or if my "concrete" view controllers should conform to it?

One thought was that if my `BaseMessageViewController` conforms to it then my concrete view controllers would automatically conform to it because of class inheritance? But I'm not seeing any warnings in my concrete view controllers that they are not implementing a required method.

Can someone please give me a helping hand here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are messages that `BaseMessageViewController` sends to self, there's no reason to define a protocol.  Just declare the methods in `BaseMessageViewController`, and comment the declarations to describe when they are sent.

You will also need to provide implementations of the methods in `BaseMessageViewController` to suppress a compiler warning.  If you want every subclass to implement the methods, you can define the methods in `BaseMessageViewController` using this pattern:

```
- (void)processMessageCancelled {
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
    abort();
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to override methods like the way you can do with Java.. you declare some methods in your superclass and then in your subclass you can have your own implementation (if you like) of the method that is declared in the superclass or just leave it to use the superclass method.

Comment: Also is it possible to add KVO to `BaseMessageViewController` so that all my view controllers will have KVO for a property set in `BaseMessageViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of the **Abstract Base Class** vs **protocol** question.

- Use an Abstract Base Class (in Cocoa these are called **Class Clusters**) when you'd like to define a framework, with some common concerns encapsulated by the framework and some specific concerns to be handled by sub-classes. An example could be a message parsing framework.
- Use a Protocol to define a common contract for classes that need their own object hierarchy. An example might be a media player, where 'play' and 'stop' are completely different depending on the type of media.

Alternatively, for something in-between, Justin Spahr-summers defines the 'concrete protocol' in libextobjc. . . https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc (similar to concrete interfaces in Java 8).